# GraphQL Query with object using americanexpress/nodes

Tags: java, graphql

I'm using [GraphQL JVM Client by American Express](https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes)

This is the query I like to build:

```
exercise {
  id
  name
  images(resize: {width: 512, height: 288, background: "ffffff"})
}
```

This is the DTO I have created:

```
@GraphQLProperty(name = "exercise")
public class Exercise {

  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  @GraphQLProperty(name = "images", arguments = {@GraphQLArgument(name = "resize")})
  private List<String> images;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
  }

  public void setImages(List<String> images) {
    this.images = images;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Exercise() {
  }
}
```

This is, how I want to build the query:

```
GraphQLTemplate graphQLTemplate = new GraphQLTemplate();

GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
    .url("https://domain/graphql")
    .arguments(
        new Arguments("exercise.images", new Argument("resize", ?))
    )
    .request(Exercise.class)
    .build();
```

But I do not get the correct expression for ?.

The question is, how do I pass structured parameters as argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is using the InputObject class. Your DTO can remain exactly as it is defined, simply add the argument like this:

```java
GraphQLTemplate graphQLTemplate = new GraphQLTemplate();

InputObject resizeInput = new InputObject.Builder()
  .put("width", 512)
  .put("height", 288)
  .put("background", "ffffff")
  .build();

GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
    .url("https://domain/graphql")
    .arguments(
        new Arguments("exercise.images", new Argument("resize", resizeInput))
    )
    .request(Exercise.class)
    .build();
```

You can read more about it and some of the other API uses in this post too (https://americanexpress.io/graphql-for-the-jvm/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution fits better as it works with API internals. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution working for me...

I have created a "variable" class

```
public class ResizeVariable {

  private String background;

  public ResizeVariable() {
  }

  public ResizeVariable(String background) {
    this.background = background;
  }

  public String getBackground() {
    return background;
  }

  public void setBackground(String background) {
    this.background = background;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "{background: \""+background+"\"}";
  }

}
```

and the missing thing was overriding toString() method. Then, this is possible:

```
GraphQLTemplate graphQLTemplate = new GraphQLTemplate();

GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
  .url("https://domain/graphql")
  .arguments(
    new Arguments("exercise.images",
      new Argument("resize", new ResizeVariable("ffffff")))
  )
  .request(Exercise.class)
  .build();
```

which results in the correct query.